# Get parent records with 0 children in SOQL

Tags: soql

So this would be possible with a roll-up summary, but since there's a limit on the number of these available, I'm trying to accomplish it without the roll-up summary field.

Via SOQL I need to get a list of parent records (for example Accounts) which have 0 children (for example Contacts).

Ideally it'd be something along these lines, but alas no luck:

```
select Id
from Account
where (select count() from Contacts) = 0
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

```
select Id
from Account
where Id not in (select AccountId from Contact)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when there are a large # of contacts (lets say a million).  Won't this query hit limits

Comment: I agree with you @NSjonas because it will fail when there will more than 50k of contacts in database.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for parent Id of the child records to get this.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)
```

Comment: This answer was posted about 10 minutes after I posted my answer...

Comment: This is normally happening when people helping the community in parallel with different questions. While replying to you some others putting comments for theirs one. After looking at them and come back, hit enter for yours some similar answers can be there..